# The computer name in the terminal isn't showing

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I start my terminal I don't see username@computername $, rather I see username $ only. How do I revert back to it's original form?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you changed the file `~/.bashrc`.

To edit it run

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

You could try using [this](https://gist.github.com/marioBonales/1637696) Default Version of the file `~/.bashrc`

Interesting for your problem are the lines starting with `PS1=...`. there you need to set the `\h` which will be replaced by your PC's hostname.

Make sure that after the changes you run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to make your changes take effect